# Optocoupler with cascaded photodiodes

Tags: opto-isolator, photodiode

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLMyt5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is there a component like in the dashed box? It may supply gate voltage for a source-to-source pair of N-channel MOSFETs. Speed is not a concern as it would be a slow relay-replacement switch. Photovoltaic output may be like 5 to 8 V/10 to 100 μA (10~15 photodiodes in series)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, those components exist! They are called photovoltaic optocouplers.

One part that fits your requirements is the [TLP3906](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/TLP3906_datasheet_en_20191222.pdf?did=15186&prodName=TLP3906) from Toshiba.

Digi-Key has them in the category [Optoisolators - Transistor, Photovoltaic Output](https://www.digikey.de/en/products/filter/optoisolators-transistor-photovoltaic-output/903)

Comment: Jonathan, it was lightning fast...the category name is a bit misleading as no transistor at the receiving side, so I might not found it... thanks a lot!!

Comment: That category includes both types: transistor output and photovoltaic output. That's what that comma is doing, between "transistor" and "photovoltaic". It's a list.

Comment: @novakt62 And note that they _are_ really slow. I see that you wrote in your question that speed isn't important, but expect up to 1 ms of switching.